# flask gunicorn pass custom parameters for every other concurrent user

Tags: python, nginx, flask, webserver, wsgi

```
value1 = "hi"
value2 = "hello"

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    return value1
```

when user1 alone make request to our server we want to send  "hi"
when user2 alone make request to our server we want to send  " hi"
if we getting 2 user simultaneously making request we want to display
user1 "hi" and
user2 "hello"

tools using :
1.flask
2.gunicorn
3.ngnix

or these is any way by ngnix, that if user1 make request to home route we send that to, /u1 in to handle_request and also same for user2 unless we have 2 user simultaneously send first to /u1 and send second to /u2 only if the both making request to / route

is these any way or similar if, please let me know